# Replacing variable with @rollup/plugin-replace throws error

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup, rollupjs, svelte-3

### Problem

I am trying to inject / replace environment variables with *@rollup/plugin-replace*. Unfortunately, I get this error:

> TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

### Code

```
// rollup.config.js
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import { config } from "dotenv";
config();

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    replace({
      values: { YOUTUBE_API: JSON.stringify(process.env.YOUTUBE_API) },
      preventAssignment: true,
    }),
  // ...
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
  onMount(() => {
    (async function getPopular() {
      videos = await axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos", {
        part: "id, snippet, suggestions",
        chart: "mostPopular",
        key: YOUTUBE_API,
      });
    })();
  });
```

### What I tried

I logged out the variable and so can confirm that it exists. Also, if I remove the `stringify` function, I get another error:

> ReferenceError: blablabblub is not defined

I have done this successfully in other projects. What the heck is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

So after some digging around with the same issue, I found it was related to object assignment. For example:

```js
export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    replace({
      values: {
        env: {
          API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
          API_VERSION: process.env.API_VERSION,
        }
      },
      preventAssignment: true,
    }),
  // ...
}
```

```js
// in some JS or Svelte file
const config = {
    host: env.API_URL,
    version: env.API_VERSION
}

// The above will result in a reference error of 'env' not being defined. 

// in the same JS or Svelte file..
const envVars = env;
const config = {
    host: envVars.API_URL,
    version: envVars.API_VERSION
}

// this works just fine!
```

I haven't had anymore time to investigate, but my gut feeling is that rollup won't replace variable names when they are nested inside an object assignment. It might be nice for an optional flag to allow this, but it might also get very messy hence why they didn't do it.

I hope this helps if it's still an issue for you.